# Calibrate a display without a colorimeter

Tags: xorg, color-management, icc

I have an old laptop with a display with bad color reproduction.
I want to try to create a specific color profile for this display. But I don't have any color calibration devices, and want to do it by eye. But I can't find any software that can do it. I want to correct a color profile (e.g. color balance, gamma) and see my changes in online mode.

Is it possible?

Comment: any options in this link for you? https://www.fossmint.com/color-picking-tools-for-linux/

Comment: I think no. These apps are only for color picking from screen.